# @XmlJavaTypeAdapter vs @XmlSchemaType with java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: web-services, netbeans, jaxb, glassfish, jax-ws

I am developping in Netbeans (8) a JAXWS (Deployed on Glassfish 4.0) in an EJB module and a JAVAFX client. I am building my WS from Java classes direction with the IDE. I am struggling with **passing java.time.LocalDateTime through the WS** and getting the LocalDateTime in the client.

It is important, that I **need/would like to develop the server and the client together**! If I change the WS, the WSDL changes, it should be propagated by Netbeans (via JAXWS) to the client-source-code at once (type-safe)... , but it somehow does not work out with java.time(.localdate)..

***Somewhy the WS does not write anything into LocalDateTime fields during marshalling. Why?
Is it a good method I use?*** Do I miss something? Thanks.

If I use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter in WebService to handle **LocalDateTime marshalling to String**, XSD generation puts xs:string to my localDateTime fields... so @XMLSchemaType is overriden by @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. **How can I resolve this?**

On the **Sever side**, in the WebService, I am using **package level**

```
    @XmlSchemaTypes({
      @XmlSchemaType(name="date", type=LocalDate.class)
      ,@XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime", type=LocalDateTime.class)
      ,@XmlSchemaType(name="time", type=LocalTime.class)
    })
```

This makes the IDE generate correct XSD elements e.g. containing

```
    <xs:element name="validTo" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The **XmlADapter on server**: (If I inject it with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter **(String, LocalDateTime)**, then XSD generation creates String from LocalDateTime.)

```
    public class LocalDateTimeAdapter
        extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime>{
        @Override
        public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(v,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        }
        @Override
        public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) throws Exception {
            return v.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        }
    }
```

**On the Client side,** I attached the WS, let the IDE generate classes.
I added an external **binding file** to the attached Webservice and an **Adapter** class to handle LocalDateTime fields:

**Binding file:**

```
            <jxb:globalBindings>
                <jxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      parseMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.printDateTime" />
                <jxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xs:date"
                      parseMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.parseDate"
                      printMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.printDate" />
                <jxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalTime" xmlType="xs:time"
                      parseMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.parseTime"
                      printMethod="test.app.utils.JaxBDateConverter.printTime" />

            </jxb:globalBindings>

        </jxb:bindings> 
    </jxb:bindings>
```

**Adapter class on Client**:
        package test.app.client;

```
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.LocalTime;
    import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

    public class JaxBDateConverter {

    static final DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
    static final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    static final DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;

    public static LocalDateTime parseDateTime(String s) {
        try {
            if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
            }
            LocalDateTime r = LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf);
            return r;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String printDateTime(LocalDateTime d) {
        try {
            if (d == null)
                return null;
            return d.format(dtf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    public static LocalDate parseDate(String s) {
        try {
            if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
            }
            LocalDate r = LocalDate.parse(s, df);
            return r;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String printDate(LocalDate d) {
        try {
            if (d == null)
                return null;
            return d.format(df);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }
    public static LocalTime parseTime(String s) {
        try {
            if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            } else {
            }
            LocalTime r = LocalTime.parse(s, tf);
            return r;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String printTime(LocalTime d) {
        try {
            if (d == null)
                return null;
            return d.format(tf);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Somewhy the WS does not write anything into LocalDateTime fields
>   during marshalling. Why? Is it a good method I created? Do I miss
>   something? Thanks.

The `java.time.LocalDateTime` type has been added since the latest JAXB (JSR-222) was released so for now you require an `XmlAdapter` to handle the conversion.

---

> If I use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter in WebService to handle LocalDateTime
>   marshalling, XSD generation puts xs:string to my localDateTime
>   fields... so @XMLSchemaType is overrided by @XmlJavaTypeAdapter. How
>   can I resolve this?

`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` doesn't override `@XmlSchemaType`.  Instead the referenced `XmlAdapter` is converting `LocalDateTime` into a `String`.  Now is far as JAXB is concerned it's now a `String` property so the `@XmlSchemaType` no longer applies.

---

> How can I resolve this?

You can use the `@XmlSchemaType` annotation directly on the adapted `LocalDateTime` property.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
@XmlSchemaType(name="dateTime")
public LocalDateTime getMyLocalDateTime() {
    return myLocalDateTime;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by adapted LocalDateTime? I already have the XmlSchemaType. What exactly should I do? And yes I tried XMLAdapter on the Server-side: XmlAdapter<String,LocalDateTime> (I forgot to put it into the post)

Comment: @AttilaKuti - Probably easiest to keep this question focused on the server side part and remove the client aspects (or make it its own question).

Comment: Yes, it is a bit complex, but it is relevant and important, that I need/would like to develop the server and the client together! If I change the WS, it will be propagated to the client at once (type-safe)... or it should be, but it somehow does not work out with java.time(.localdate)...

Comment: @AttilaKuti - I have updated my answer to address your first comment.

Comment: I guess you meant LocalDateTime. I have already tried to put annotations on field level and also on getter methods... it works the same as on package level. (I guess this is not the problem..) I might have to "stabelize" my WSDL and then apply XmlAdapters on Server... in this case GF Server will not update WSDL of WS... if i change WS, then I have to disable XmlAdapters and manually have to let the server refresh the WSDL... etc. (I guess... still not tested)

Comment: @AttilaKuti - I still think it's easier if we first solve the issue of getting the XML Schema generated with the appropriate schema types.